# XSL-FO Table Border Inconsistent

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to reduce the border width to 0.5px or 0.5pt but the table cell borders are inconsistent.

The table cell borders, some are thin and some are thick.
Is there any way to have a thin border and have a consistent thickness.

Sample Table code is below.

```
            <table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border="0.5pt solid black">
              <table-header border="inherit">
                <table-row border="inherit" font-weight="bold" font-size="10pt" text-align="left" color="#ffffff" background-color="#9cc568" >
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>test1</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>test2</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>test3</block>
                  </table-cell>
                </table-row>
              </table-header>
              <table-body border="inherit">
                <table-row border="inherit" font-weight="bold" font-size="10pt" text-align="left" color="#ffffff" background-color="#9cc568" >
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell1</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell2</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell3</block>
                  </table-cell>
                </table-row>
              </table-body>
              <table-body border="inherit">
                <table-row border="inherit" font-weight="bold" font-size="10pt" text-align="left" color="#ffffff" background-color="#9cc568" >
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell1</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell2</block>
                  </table-cell>
                  <table-cell border="inherit" margin="0pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4" text-align="left">
                    <block>cell3</block>
                  </table-cell>
                </table-row>
              </table-body>
            </table>
```

Comment: FYI, `margin` does not apply to `fo:table-cell`.

Comment: Which formatter are you using?  Where do you see the inconsistent borders: when viewing PDF, when printed, or ...?  Do you notice any difference when you use 'px' compared to when you use 'pt'?

Comment: I am using border="0.5pt solid black" attribute for table-cell borders. I am viewing in PDF rendered by Salesforce CPQ in Chrome. I tried printing as well, its the same issue.

Comment: As far as I know the `border` property in XSL 1.1 is not defined as inheritable. See [7.31.3 "border"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#border). The `inherited` is one of the possible value. But it is defined as "Inherited: no".

Comment: You are looking at the answer how? Zoom in and out and you will see border sizes change, Print the document and see if they are different sizes. What you likely see are the web browser/plugin interpretation of a size they cannot represent.

Comment: One mistake: `inherited` forces the formatter to adopt non-inheritable property to be inherited. So it should be worked as inherited.

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to have the same issue. I know it's too late might be helpful to others who face this. There was no problem with my code.

The one that caused this error was Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Just click Edit-->preferences-->page display and then in rendering grouping uncheck the Enhance thin lines then the lines in my PDF appeared fine.

if that doesn't change it.

try changing your border size equal to or more than**1pt**.

Comment: I swear to god man, I love you! In my case google chrome didn't show the right result. Adope did display it right !